# How to write .json file in codeigniter using angular.js

Tags: php, angularjs, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to create todo app.anyone suggest me how to write code for fetch data from database and display using json using angular.js.

Comment: question is too broad and doesn't point a real problem

Comment: I suggest you to read the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) of CodeIgniter

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from database:
[How to retrieve data from the database and display it in a html table using Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986379/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-database-and-display-it-in-a-html-table-using-code)

For angular :
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Note: your question is too broad and doesn't point a real problem, you should ask questions about a problem not tutorials or how to ...