# Fetch data and display it in a table in with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could anyone help me fetch data from a database and view it in a table? I am new to codeigniter framework.

Comment: you can do this from function mysql_query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986379/how-to-retrieve-data-from-the-database-and-display-it-in-a-html-table-using-code

Comment: Here's the documentation, give some time to research. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Answer (score 0):

here is a short Code for fetching Data from an SQL-Table

First you create a Connection:

```
// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

The Values:
$host = your host-ip or URL or localhost
$username = Your Database Username
$password = your Database Password
$database =  your database's Name
```

Then you need to request(query) something from a Table in that Database
For Example like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Fehler:$sql");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{

}
```

Now this Code will get all the Data out of a Table and orders it by the ID Descending.
In that code $table stands for your Table-Name and $db is your Database Name, as PHP7 needs it by every Query.

The Results eg. ALL Data in the Table, ordered by ID is now stored in the single Variable $res. If you want you can use code to check 'if ($res = true)' in order to make sure that you actually get a result from the query and catch an exception.

The 'Method mysqli_fetch_assoc()' will now give you all the Data nice and easy. 
All you have to do is use this While Loop like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  $username = $row['username'];
  $date= $row['date'];
}
```

Meaning, that every While Cycle goes through one Row of results in the order you chose to query it at.
And $row acts as an Array where the Idice, ([] text in these brackets) corresponds to the given Clumn Name in your Table

Hope i could help you out :)
And please in the future state your question a little more clear and detailed and show that you have actually worked on your Problem before asking

Spytrycer

*Edit*

I overread the table part :)

In order to view it in a Table you should do something like this:

```
echo"<table border = '1'>";
echo"<tr>";
//Do <td> and </td> for as many Columns as you have and write them between the td's
echo"<td>";
echo"Column Name";
echo"</td>";

//Then comes the Data part
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Fehler:$sql");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
 //open new Row
 echo"<tr>";

   //Do this td, data, /td loop for as many Columns you have in your 
     Database. For a Database with id, username and Password for example:

   echo"<td>";
   echo"$row['id']";
   echo"</td>";

   echo"<td>";
   echo"$row['username']";
   echo"</td>";

   echo"<td>";
   echo"$row['password']";
   echo"</td>";

 echo"</tr>";
 //Close row
}
```